# Reducing outbound bandwidth costs for a file hosting site on Azure Storage?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm currently running a file hosting site as a side project and I'm using Azure Storage to actually store and serve the files. The big issue for me is that I would like to be able to support relatively large files as well, which are really expensive to serve.

According to the [pricing details](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/) for Azure outbound data transfers, it'll cost me $0.087 per GB to serve files to the user. This is okay for things like images, but if the user stores something like a 1 GB video, it'll cost me around 9 cents per person who wants to download the file. Even if I try to monetize the service, I cannot see how I can reasonably sustain these costs if the service ever becomes popular.

Does anyone have any suggestions or alternatives to reducing outbound data transfer costs?

Edit: As I come across helpful ways to reduce my costs, I'll update the list below:

- Use a free CDN provider like Cloudflare. Specifically for me, I only enabled the CDN for files served through Azure Storage, because enabling it for my whole site would impose a 100MB file size upload restriction. One thing to note is that [Cloudflare doesn't cache everything](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172516-What-file-extensions-does-CloudFlare-cache-for-static-content-), so even though I'm covered for images, I'm still out of luck for many other media types that users might upload.
- Compress uploaded files so that not as much bandwidth is used on outbound transfers.
- If you're using cloud storage but host your website on a dedicated server with generous bandwidth, you can implement some kind of local cache and serve content directly from your cache, with the storage provider being a fallback on a cache miss. Unfortunately this isn't viable for me since I also host my site on Azure, and the outbound data transfer rates apply across their entire service stack.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of your assets available publicly or do you have some kind of authentication before them? If they are available publicly then maybe a CDN would be an option here

Comment: Yes, they are publicly available. I was actually considering using a CDN, but at least for Azure, the price is exactly the same when using a CDN. I'm just wondering if there's something I'm missing about how file upload sites can sustain themselves.

Comment: Oh, I see, you're right. You could still save a bit with this due to reduced Storage Transactions but those are peanuts compared to the bandwidth costs. Other CDN providers? Maybe Amazon? Dunno if they are cheaper

Comment: Unfortunately Amazon is $0.085/gb, so I'm still not really saving much. I just checked a bunch of other cloud CDN providers and it seems like I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try caching your content on the client. For scenarios where you are accessing static content such as photos or videos, having a cache set up could keep you from having to go to the server each time you need data.